# How can I set a Silverlight DatePicker Control to be ReadOnly?

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

How can I set the `System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker` control as used within a Silverlight project to ReadOnly ?

There doesn't seem to be any properties that I can set within the Xaml or code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to?

DatePicker is a glorified combobox that drops down a calendar rather than a list. If it's to become read only then it would effectively be a read only text box?

< edit >
If it's purely for a looks thing then, then a workaround is make a copy of the controls template and edit it so that it's Disabled state looks the same as it's Active state and then set it to disabled when you need read-only behaviour.

Comment: The reason is so that I can just show the same control without having to change it to a text box in a read only situation. I would basically just need it to show the date without the user being able to change it by either typing it directly into the text box part or via the dropdown calendar.

Comment: Why would you want to? << I wonder why people always ask this question. Usually, when people end up posting a question on S.O., it's not just for the sake of asking something... As for your edit, don't mistake Disabled and ReadOnly, those are 2 different properties that do not have the same purposes, nor the same look.

Comment: There is no such property as ReadOnly on a DatePicker. As "why would you want to" there wasn't enough info in the question to understand his desired behaviour.

Comment: A very valid reason is to present the current date selected, and only allow the user to change that date when the control is in an "edit" mode. It saves from having to have to presenters and toggling the visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source code to the datepicker and added a ReadOnly property.

..and "yes" there is a worthwhile reason for having this. I wanted to have 3 states:

1. Normal
2. Disabled (grayed out look)
3. ReadOnly (not grayed out and no calendar button...also changed the border of the textbox so that it looks like a label)

3's style was my preference but specifically I wanted to differentiate between disabled controls (grayed out) and read only "visual" wise.

Wasn't sure about posting code (there's lots)...or if anyone's still interested ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem setting a new style for the DatePickerTextBox controls. This control is part of the style of the DatePicker. Then with this lines, you can make all DatePicker controls that can access to this style readonly. This only make readonly the manually editing of the date, the user can still select a date with the dropdown button.

```
<Style TargetType="prim:DatePickerTextBox">
  <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about just handling the date change event and suppressing it and reverting it back to today's date (or some other set date)?

Comment: The weakness of this approach is it looks like, to the end-user, that they can use the control to do something... but when they try their entry is "lost" and reverted. It can increase confusion in your AI. Best to visually indicate that the control is for display purposes only.

Comment: Rather make the user aware that he shouldn't even try